# How do I fix Bone Gaps?

Tags: rigging, bones

I imported my model from 3DS Max in which the bones always look nice and linked.
Here I'm struggling to make an IK Rig but the bone gaps are my biggest issue now. If I try to target the hand bone with the bone constraint, everything on the model will move towards the hand producing undesirable effects with the model's skin rig.

The thing is that all the bones are linked, it's just that the gaps are a major problem.

[image]

Comment: There are a few options in the importer window when you import a file. May be one of them solve this problem. If they not you can check in "Connected" in the bone properties tab in Edit mode which automatically snaps the ominous bone's tail to its parent's head.

Comment: @FFeller I guess it's the only option that requires exporting the model and then re-importing? And it's going to add another problem because if I have to do that then, the "leaf Bones" can't be fixed. I have facial bones and I use the "Better FBX importer" to have smaller end bones for the face. Otherwise they'd be sticking all the way out.